# rails activemerchant authorize.net problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, authorize.net, activemerchant

I have an Authorize.net account for CC processing on my ecommerce site, and I use ActiveMerchant to authoenticate transactions. It worked just fine until a while ago, and then it stopped. I cannot figure out why. When I run it in test mode, it works fine, creates the transactions and successfully authorizes the funds. But when I try with real account, it fails. When I run it from the console, here is the code:

```
cc_hash =
  :first_name         => 'Donald',
  :last_name          => 'Duck',
  :number             => '4007000000027',
  :month              => '8',
  :year               => Time.now.year+1,
  :verification_value => '000'
}
card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(cc_hash)

#--- valid?
RYeller.bar
if card.valid?
  puts "card valid"
else
  puts "card not valid"
end

#ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
#gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new(:login=>'scrubbed',:password=>'scrubbed')

ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :production
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new(:login=>'scrubbed',:password=>'scrubbed')

amount  = rand(1000)+2500 
options = {}
options[:order_id]    = "WEBSITE 26"
options[:description] = 'WEBSITE TEST'

#--- authorize transaction
response = gateway.authorize(amount, card, options)
puts response.inspect
```

When I run this in test mode, in my sandbox account (the two lines commented out in the code above) - it works fine. When I run it on my real account (the code as is above) - I get an error: "An error occurred during processing. Call Merchant Service Provider." The full response hash is:

```
#<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x1078607d8 @fraud_review=false, @params={"response_reason_code"=>"35", "avs_result_code"=>"P", "transaction_id"=>"scrubbed", "response_code"=>2, "response_reason_text"=>"An error occurred during processing. Call Merchant Service Provider.", "card_code"=>"P"}, @message="An error occurred during processing. Call Merchant Service Provider", @authorization="scrubbed", @test=false, @cvv_result={"message"=>"Not Processed", "code"=>"P"}, @success=false, @avs_result={"message"=>"Postal code matches, but street address not verified.", "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>"Y", "code"=>"P"}>
```

I am using a test CC number and the card.valid? test returns true.

When I look at the transaction in Authorize.net, I see all the transaction created and all the info properly there, but the Transaction Code is General Error.

Any ideas? Help greatly appreciated, I am at the end of my rope here and sinking fast.

Answer (score 0):

Is your production Authorize.net in test mode? If not, Donanld Duck isn't going to be able to check out with a fake credit card.

You should be able to login to your production Authorize.net account and see the test order as a decline. If you do then everything is working and you will need to test with a real card to get a successful transaction. If you want to test with a fake card you will need to set you production account back to testing.